# Why do i need a Video Player Engine even though HTML5 can do everything i need?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

**Simple question:** Why do i need a Video Player Engine like [video-js](https://videojs.com/) or [mediaelement.js](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/) even though HTML5 can do everything i need? (Playing videos in modern browsers)

**Background information:** I have a simple intranet website where i present videos in h.264/mp4 to my team.

**Code example:**

```
<video controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="auto" poster="/images/nothumbnail.png">
    <source src="/static/testvideo01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/static/testvideo01.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: First of all, this is not a question for Stack Overflow. Second, you don't *need* them, but they provide you with controls and api to make working with videos easier.

Comment: why is this not a question for so? i'm asking if i should implement a feature (video) certain ways or if this is in 2019 no longer required. I can not find an answer for this on the internet.

Comment: @gooleem you should maybe ask your question here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or may be here: https://video.stackexchange.com/. That's probably what Isaac Vidrine meant by not a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: You don't "need" it unless you're supporting older browsers, and I'm talking OLD browsers (Previous to IE9). So unless your clients haven't updated to at least windows XP service pack 3, just use video tags!

[Click here to check out how many people don't actually have support for the video element.](https://caniuse.com/#search=video)

Answer (score 2):

It's not required if you are playing a simple mp4.

But if you wish to have more advanced features, such as live streaming, adaptive bitrate switching, ad insertion, analytics, etc, a player or player framework will do all that and much more.